# How can I show part of a .log file in latex

Tags: latex

How can I show part of a `.log` file in latex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to include verbatim material like .log files. I prefer the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  language={[latex]TeX},
  tabsize=2,
  breaklines,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
}


\begin{document}

text

\begin{lstlisting}
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.7.14)  16 JUL 2021 15:17
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```